# How to edit the style of items in the File Explorer view

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to write a VSCode extension that changes the style of a file or folder according to globs specified in settings.json.  For example, I want to set the `opacity` of an item to `0.5` if the file is an auto-generated `.d.ts` file.  Currently, I can *hide* those files using the `files.exclude` setting, and I want to do basically the same thing using `files.dim`.

```
{
    "files.dim": {
        "**/*.d.ts": { "when": "$(basename).ts" }
    }
}
```

The thing is, I can't find any way to access the File Explorer view from the VSCode API.  Is it even accessible?

Comment: you can access the colors, maybe others but i've only looked at modifying colors. The variables are names like: list.activeSelectionBackground, list.hoverForeground and others.  Don't know if that helps or not.

Comment: @dx_over_dt, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @JordanKohl nope